# Getting last shown view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

Is it possible to get last shown view controller in AppDelegate in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Thanks for answering=)

Comment: When you are back from background, or when you start the app ?

Comment: When I am back from background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `rootViewController` is `UINavigationController`, you can get is topViewController

```
 UINavigationController *nav = 
  (UINavigationController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
 [nav.topViewController view].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If you have a `UITabBarController` as `rootViewController`

```
 UITabBarController *nav = 
  (UITabBarController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
 [nav.selectedViewController view].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: of course not, root is root ! In 99% time root is a navigationController or a TabBarController, so we can ask to this "nav" for the current selected/displayed ViewController. Now if you push by code a modal VC, this code did not work.

Comment: exactly! and what i need is to know current... But how can i get it?

Comment: I get you the exemples : `nav.topViewController` or  `nav.selectedViewController`(depend on root type)